# Plotting Multiple Lines Graph from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a large data set containing years, NFL teams, their total salaries paid out for that year, and more misc stats. I want to create a plot that has the years on the x-axis, total salaries on the y and then has multiple lines, one for each team.

The data I want to plot looks something like this except there are of course way more teams and years and the total salaries are accurate:

| Year | Team | Salaries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | Miami | $100 |
| 2015 | Denver | $150 |
| 2015 | LA | $125 |
| 2016 | Miami | $125 |
| 2016 | Denver | $100 |
| 2016 | LA | $100 |

I know pandas plot function and I can set the x-axis but when I set y to be total salaries it just gives me a single line. I also do not know how to set it to break up the data by each team so each team is treated as a separate line.

Comment: read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: As you say, you really have two questions. You should try to solve them individually. There will be answers out there for both.
Use pandas pivot to get a new column per team: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html
Once you've got that, the plotting is easy.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use a pivot table to get a new column per team.

Once you've got the data reshaped like this, plotting is easy. Check out the documentation on [pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#pivot-tables).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
     {
         "Year": ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"] * 6,
         "Team": ["Miami", "Denver", "LA"] * 8,
         "Salaries": [100, 200, 150, 125, 100, 250] * 4,
     }
)

df.pivot_table(values="Salaries",index="Year",columns="Team").plot()
```

The result of the pivot table looks like this

```
Team    Denver  LA  Miami
Year            
2015    100 150 100
2016    200 250 125
2017    100 150 100
2018    200 250 125
```

And the plot:
[image]

Comment: hi @ChristianFett, another way of thanking here is [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative via `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Year": ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"] * 6,
        "Team": ["Miami", "Denver", "LA"] * 8,
        "Salaries": [100, 200, 150, 125, 100, 250] * 4,
    }
)


sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Salaries', hue='Team', data=df)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

*NOTE:* Thanks to [@Cornelius Roemer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7483211/cornelius-roemer) for the model data.

Comment: Ah nice that Seaborn has the pivot built in! You stole my model data though :p

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer yup `hue` parameter is quite handy. Thanks for the model data  : )